# Exception while running Hazelcast-Jet 0.5.1 code samples

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I am trying to run Hazelcast jet 0.5.1 code samples. I am getting following exception while running Hazelcast code samples:

> \streaming\map-journal-source\src\main\java\MapJournalSource.java & \streaming\map-journal-source\src\main\java\RemoteMapJournalSource.java

The log details are as follows.

```
06:21,465 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] Starting Jet 0.5.1 (20171206 - a2156c6)
06:21,485 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] Setting number of cooperative threads and default parallelism to 4
06:21,486 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] 
    o   o   o   o---o o---o o     o---o   o   o---o o-o-o        o o---o o-o-o
    |   |  / \     /  |     |     |      / \  |       |          | |       |  
    o---o o---o   o   o-o   |     o     o---o o---o   |          | o-o     |  
    |   | |   |  /    |     |     |     |   |     |   |      \   | |       |  
    o   o o   o o---o o---o o---o o---o o   o o---o   o       o--o o---o   o   
06:21,488 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2017, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
06:23,670 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.136.97.81]:5701 - 2b97f390-956e-4428-a9ce-4239f9304f47 this
]

06:24,141 [10.136.97.81]:5702 [jet] [0.5.1] Starting Jet 0.5.1 (20171206 - a2156c6)
06:24,141 [10.136.97.81]:5702 [jet] [0.5.1] Setting number of cooperative threads and default parallelism to 4
06:24,141 [10.136.97.81]:5702 [jet] [0.5.1] 
    o   o   o   o---o o---o o     o---o   o   o---o o-o-o        o o---o o-o-o
    |   |  / \     /  |     |     |      / \  |       |          | |       |  
    o---o o---o   o   o-o   |     o     o---o o---o   |          | o-o     |  
    |   | |   |  /    |     |     |     |   |     |   |      \   | |       |  
    o   o o   o o---o o---o o---o o---o o   o o---o   o       o--o o---o   o   
06:24,141 [10.136.97.81]:5702 [jet] [0.5.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2017, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
06:24,359 [10.136.97.81]:5702 [jet] [0.5.1] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.136.97.81]:5701
06:31,373 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [10.136.97.81]:5701 - 2b97f390-956e-4428-a9ce-4239f9304f47 this
    Member [10.136.97.81]:5702 - fb5accd3-cc74-4d7e-af5e-fbf873a073eb
]

06:31,389 [10.136.97.81]:5702 [jet] [0.5.1] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [10.136.97.81]:5701 - 2b97f390-956e-4428-a9ce-4239f9304f47
    Member [10.136.97.81]:5702 - fb5accd3-cc74-4d7e-af5e-fbf873a073eb this
]

06:33,867 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] Starting job ed01-cc0f-d21c-1437 based on join/submit request from client
06:33,886 [10.136.97.81]:5701 [jet] [0.5.1] java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleException(SerializationUtil.java:63)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:273)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:570)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.CustomClassLoadedObject.read(CustomClassLoadedObject.java:55)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.core.Vertex.readData(Vertex.java:193)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:267)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:570)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.core.DAG.readData(DAG.java:323)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:185)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.CustomClassLoadedObject.deserializeWithCustomClassLoader(CustomClassLoadedObject.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterContext.deserializeDAG(MasterContext.java:294)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterContext.tryStartJob(MasterContext.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.tryStartJob(JobCoordinationService.java:266)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.submitOrJoinJob(JobCoordinationService.java:202)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JetService.submitJob(JetService.java:215)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.SubmitJobOperation.doRun(SubmitJobOperation.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.AsyncExecutionOperation.run(AsyncExecutionOperation.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:194)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:406)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:433)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:569)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:554)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:513)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobProxy.invokeOp(JobProxy.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobProxy.invokeSubmitJob(JobProxy.java:61)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.AbstractJobProxy.<init>(AbstractJobProxy.java:83)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobProxy.<init>(JobProxy.java:47)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JetInstanceImpl.newJob(JetInstanceImpl.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.JetInstance.newJob(JetInstance.java:70)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.JetInstance.newJob(JetInstance.java:86)
    at MapJournalSource.main(MapJournalSource.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1584)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1156)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1817)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.CustomClassLoadedObject$Serializer.read(CustomClassLoadedObject.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.CustomClassLoadedObject$Serializer.read(CustomClassLoadedObject.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:267)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1150)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization
    at MapJournalSource.$deserializeLambda$(MapJournalSource.java:1)
    ... 60 more
Read 0 entries from map journal.
```

Will you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=MapJournalSource` and it runs just fine. I used version from the `0.5-maintenance` branch, which is the default. Deserialization error should not happen if everything is run from single VM. How did you run the sample?

Comment: Thanks @Oliv for your help. The code sample worked with above maven command. I was trying to run this with Eclipse and facing the exception posted above.